# Class java.util.Map not public or does not allow instantiation with auto generated classes in WebService

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, jaxws-maven-plugin

I have a WSDL provided by a partner, based on the OTA standard http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05.

I generated a Java Client using jaxws-maven-plugin to auto generate Java classes.
The port is available through a ServiceClient that provides the methods. Until here, no problem at all.

The problems come when, for testing purposes, we need to create a mock implementation of the WebService.

I've done this with other WebServices and didn't get any errors, but for this one I get the following error when implementing the Interface's method:

> Web method problem:Class java.util.Map not public or does not allow
>   instantiation

So my interface looks like this:

```
@WebService(name = "DistributorsV1Port", targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
        ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface ServiceMock extends ServiceDispatcher<Object, Object> {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetMultiAvailability")
    @WebResult(name = "OTA_HotelAvailRS", targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05", partName = "response")
    public OTAHotelAvailRS getMultiAvailability(
        @WebParam(name = "OTA_HotelAvailRQ", targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05", partName = "request")
                OTAHotelAvailRQ request);
```

And the implementation is as follows:

```
@WebService(name = "DistributorsV1Port", targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
        ObjectFactory.class
})
public class ServiceMockImpl extends ServiceDispatcherImpl<Object, Object> implements ServiceMock {

    @Override
    public OTAHotelAvailRS getMultiAvailability(OTAHotelAvailRQ request) {
        return (OTAHotelAvailRS) dispatch(request);
    }
}
```

So what I understand, is that one of the attributes of the OTAHotelAvailRQ is a map, and @WebService doesn't like returning Maps. But this class has been auto generated by jax-ws plugin, so I'm getting a bit lost.

This is the attribute:

```
@XmlAnyAttribute
private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap();
```

If more code is helpful, please request the classes you would like to see.

Comment: Map is an interface so no way to instantiate it. Try to make it class `HashMap<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap()` (need to adapt getter/setter as well)

Comment: I get that, But this is a class auto-generated by jaxws-maven-plugin, So why would it generate a class that can't be sent through a ws?

Comment: It can be sent. I think problem is parsing when the Map should be instantiated. Could be WS uses e.g. LinkedHashMap to keep order.

Comment: I see, but then I don't know what I can do, as I don't control what type of map the attribute is defined, as this is an external library I use with the auto-gen classes. Even If I altered the client, the jaxws plugin will re-generate this classes on maven install/package etc...

Comment: Try to use `<jaxb:globalBindings ` and define a binding customization file https://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/enhancing-jaxb-artifacts to use desired implementation for maps (e.g. LinkedHashMap always). Have not tried myself

Comment: I haven't found anything related to map implementation in custom bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was finally solved by removing:

```
@WebService(name = "DistributorsV1Port", targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
        ObjectFactory.class
})
```

From the implementation. As those annotations are inherited, I didn't need them there, and then IntelliJ won't complain anymore.

Anyways, having them there shouldn't be a problem, and I guess this is an issue with IntelliJ's warnings.